# phpmyadmin warning, "The additional features for working with linked tables have been deactivated"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, linked-tables

In the footer of the phpmyadmin homepage is a warning that reads, **"The additional features for working with linked tables have been deactivated. To find out why click here."**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should set up the phpMyAdmin configuration storage to benefit from many interesting features. See http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage.

Comment: Also, if you don't wish to use these features, you can remove the corresponding lines from config.inc.php to disable the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `SQL` its from the **phpAdmin documentation(linked-tables topic)**:

```
GRANT USAGE ON mysql.* TO 'pma'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pmapass';
GRANT SELECT (
    Host, User, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv,
    Create_priv, Drop_priv, Reload_priv, Shutdown_priv, Process_priv,
    File_priv, Grant_priv, References_priv, Index_priv, Alter_priv,
    Show_db_priv, Super_priv, Create_tmp_table_priv, Lock_tables_priv,
    Execute_priv, Repl_slave_priv, Repl_client_priv
    ) ON mysql.user TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.db TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.host TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT (Host, Db, User, Table_name, Table_priv, Column_priv)
    ON mysql.tables_priv TO 'pma'@'localhost';
```

Comment: This is only part of the SQL needed; this grants the proper permissions but doesn't actually create the table structure. The link posted by Marc has the information about fully activating the feature.

Answer (score 0):

This warning will appears anytime you upgrade the phpMyAdmin version.

For Ubuntu Users, please find the solution at here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/261858/the-phpmyadmin-configuration-storage-is-not-completely-configured